# How to find a sentence with the most words in a list in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
A =["I like apple"]
B =["I like playing basketball"]
C =["how are you doing"]
listt=[A,B,C]
```

I need to return the string with the most words in a list (in this example it's B and C).

first, I want to count number of words in each string, but my code doesn't work. Does anyone know how to return the string that has the most words?

`number = len(re.findall(r'\w+',listt))`

Comment: Do you mean you want to return all items from the list but the one with the least amount of words in it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `max`:

```
print(max(A+B+C,key=lambda x: len(x.split())))
```

If wanna show both:

```
print([i for i in A+B+C if i == max(A+B+C,key=lambda x: len(x.split()))])
```

Comment: Doesn't this go by length of the string, not number of words?

Comment: @user24343 Done my edit.

Comment: The OP wanted to show B and C as the output, this shows only B.
Check my answer.

Comment: @AbhinayPandey Look at second example!

Comment: You can't use split() here as all dots or commas in `three . . , word , , , sentence` will be counted as words.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[len(i[0].split(' ')) for i in listt]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just `.count` the spaces (separating words): `[s for s in sentences if s.count(' ') == max(s.count(' ') for s in sentences)]` (`s[0]` if you have each sentence in a separate list and maybe getting `max` first to save time)

If your words can also be separated by any punctuation, you will probably want to use `re`, as in your example, just `findall`ing on *every sentence*, like this:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\w+')
# note I changed some stuff to have words only separated by punctuation
sentences = [["I like:apple"], ["I (really)like playing basketball"], ["how are you doing"]]
current_s = []
current_len = 0
for s in sentences:
    no = len(pattern.findall(s[0]))  # [0] because you have each sentence in a separate list
    if no == current_len:
        current_s.append(s)
    elif no > current_len:
        current_s = [s]
        current_len = no
print('the most number of words is', current_len)
print('\n'.join(current_s))
```

Answer (score 0):

After researching, I found this using `max` function.
using max function to count the maximum words, then printing the words with maximum words.

```
A ="I like apple"
B ="I like playing basketball" 
C ="how are you doing"
sentences=[A,B,C]

max_words=max(len(x.split(' ')) for x in sentences)

print([i for i in sentences if len(i.split(' '))==max_words])
```

Basic logic of python, without any special function:

```
A ="I like apple"
B ="I like playing basketball" 
C ="how are you doing"
sentences=[A,B,C]
max_words=0

for sentence in sentences:
    if len(sentence.split(' '))>max_words:
        max_words=len(sentence.split(' '))

for sentence in sentences:
    if len(sentence.split(' '))==max_words:
        print (sentence)

print(max_sentences)
```

Comment: Noted.next time don't forget :-)

Comment: Yeah Surely! :)

Answer (score 0):

Split the sentences and order by number of words:

```
A = ["I like apple"]
B = ["I like playing basketball"]
C = ["how are you doing today?"]

sorted_sentences = sorted([(sentence, len(sentence[0].split(' '))) for sentence in [A, B, C]], key=lambda x: x[1],
                      reverse=True)
print('The sentence: "{}" has the maximum number of words: {}'.format(sorted_sentences[0][0],sorted_sentences[0][1]))
```

Output

```
The sentence: "['how are you doing today?']" has the maximum number of words: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = ["I like apple"]
B = ["I like playing basketball"]
C = ["how are you doing"]

items = A + B + C

longest_length = len(max(items, key=lambda k: len(k.split())).split())
result = [i for i in items if len(i.split()) == longest_length]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['I like playing basketball', 'how are you doing']
```

Please notice that [max](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_max.htm) function and not the length of the string:

> The method max() returns the max alphabetical character from the string str.

That is why I'm using key lambda function to change default comparison to the number of words in the string `key=lambda k: len(k.split())`